# Is there a way to create a background which will be specifically located images which will also be screen size responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create like a background that will be made of images placed in specific locations, which also be screen size responsive, check out the images I made in photoshop to make it more clear.
Does anyone know how it can be done?
enter image description here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsHvc.jpg

Comment: Have you looked into CSS positioning? You could do this several ways, like using a `div` for each image and positioning its left, right, top etc. Play with some code and then repost how close you got. People here tend to downvote questions simply asking for code without having tried something.

Comment: Alright man, thanks a lot I will try that.

Comment: @Bman70 worked like a charm
You can check out the website here https://scooteraki-beta.netlify.com/
I used (position: fixed) with some padding and works now just like I wanted it to.
Thank youuuu

Comment: Congrats on getting it working, looks great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/7922428/bman70
I used position fixed and it worked perfectly.
Here is the link to the website: https://scooteraki-beta.netlify.com/
And here is what I used:

```
.background-image-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -75px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```